# Printing int using putchar() in C

Tags: c

I have just discovered that to print an integer using the `putchar()` function, I need to add `'0'`.
What is the importance of this `'0'`?

Comment: The glyph `4` is (almost certainly) represented by the integer 52.  If you want to print a `4`, you need to `putchar(52)`. `0` is represented by 48.  If you `putchar(4)`, the terminal will attempt to display `eot`.  But `'0' + '4' == 52`, so `putchar('4' + '0')` will cause the terminal to display the glyph `4`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Actually, `'0' + '4' == 100`, which will print as `d` (assuming ASCII-compatible encoding).  You mean `'0' + 4`.

Comment: @dan04 Yes, thanks.  Too late to edit. :(

Comment: But, really, you just want `putchar('4')`.

Comment: It does not matter what the values of the digit characters are: `'0' + 0` is `'0'` (which should be obvious), and `'0' + 1` is `'1'`, and so on, because the 10 digit characters are guaranteed to be in ascending, consecutive order. Adding `'0'` converts the single-digit value to the corresponding character.

Comment: Or, to be even more efficient, you could do `'0'|n` instead of `'0'+n`.

Comment: @user16217248 How "efficient"?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Bitwise operators are faster than addition

Comment: If it's not obvious by now, the fundamental issue here is that `putchar` works with *characters*, or with *text*.  It does not work with things that have a numeric value in the conventional sense.  Every character it can print has a code, almost certainly in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  `A` has code 65.  `$` has code 36.  The space character has code 32.  And the `0` character — the one you get when you type that key to the right of the 9 key on your keyboard — has code 48.

Comment: So if you called `putchar(7)`, you'd get the character with the code 7, *not* the character `7`.  To get the character `7`, you need code 55.  Now, not surprisingly, code 55 is exactly 7 more than 48.  So you could call `putchar(55)`, or `putchar(48 + 7)`.  Or you could call `putchar('0' + 7)`, since `'0'` gives you the code for the character `0`.

Comment: @user16217248 Granting that that _may_ be true in some architectures, why suggest "non-idiom" solutions that a competent compiler will optimise for anyway. The hardware doesn't care about picoseconds difference, but the human readers will spend 5 minutes wondering "why? what is this supposed to do?" So, when describing it as "efficient", perhaps more clarity is needed explaining what you mean. Just a suggestion. :-)

Comment: A useful read on `+` vs `|`: [Why is addition as fast as bit-wise operations in modern processors](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75811/why-is-addition-as-fast-as-bit-wise-operations-in-modern-processors) In olden times, it was worth playing compiler for this stuff. Today it isn’t, unless you have benchmarks that say you should. But **user16217248** is correct that bitwise-or is _still_ more efficient than addition.

Comment: @user16217248 I'll pay you $100 if you can conduct a convincing demonstration (on an actual computer) that `putchar('0' | n)` is faster than `putchar('0' + n)`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Using bitwise or with ASCII values is an exceedingly common and very old idiom. The ASCII character set was designed with that in mind. (I’ll agree with everyone that addition is a better choice of operator for humans here.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas "Common and very old" describes me, but for this OP using such an 'i', 'd', 'i', 'o', 'm' is being an 'i', 'd', 'i', 'o', ('m' ^ 0x19)... (or simply too clever.)

Comment: Even if `|` does happen to be faster than `+`, the fact that you're writing to a stream (possibly one redirected to a file on a slow magnetic disk, or on a network share), will generally take *much* more of your computer's time than some simple ASCII arithmetic anyway.

Comment: Meh, AFAIC ASCII should be considered dead. Program all generalized text transformations using ICU, which exists on all modern systems except for special-purpose microcontrollers. @dan04 Exactly. Care only if profiling says it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this bit of code and its output will help clarify...

```
int main() {
    for( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ) {
        printf( "%d (binary) transformed to printable ASCII ", i );
        putchar( '0' + i );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for( char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++ ) {
        putchar( c );
        printf( " (%02X hex) printable ASCII char for binary %d\n", c, c - '0' );
    }

    printf( "'Count' up the (uppercase) ASCII alphabet\n" );
    for( int l = 0; l < 26; l++ )
        putchar( 'A' + l );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Abridged Output

```
0 (binary) transformed to printable ASCII 0
1 (binary) transformed to printable ASCII 1
2 (binary) transformed to printable ASCII 2
...
8 (binary) transformed to printable ASCII 8
9 (binary) transformed to printable ASCII 9
0 (30 hex) printable ASCII char for binary 0
1 (31 hex) printable ASCII char for binary 1
2 (32 hex) printable ASCII char for binary 2
...
8 (38 hex) printable ASCII char for binary 8
9 (39 hex) printable ASCII char for binary 9
'Count' up the (uppercase) ASCII alphabet
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 5):

The argument to `putchar` is [the ASCII code](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp)* of the `char` you want to print.  The digits `0` thru `9` are encoded as the consecutive numbers 48 thru 57.  So, to print the one-digit *number* `n`, you can write:

```
putchar(48 + n);
```

Without the addition of the constant 48, you wouldn't get digit; you'd get [a control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) such as Backspace (8) or Tab (9).

But it's preferable to write

```
putchar('0' + n);
```

Because in C, a single-quoted character literal has a numeric value equal to its ASCII code, so `'0'` is just another way to write 48, but has the advantage of not requiring you (or a future maintenance developer) to memorize the ASCII chart to *know* that `'0' == 48`.

---

(*Technically, the C standard doesn't assume an ASCII-compatible character set, and C compilers exist for EBCDIC systems.  But that's probably not relevant to a beginner.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code, please

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        putchar (n + '0');
        
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: ... please what?